# Jodd Message parsing failed

Tags: jodd

I'm using Jodd version 3.7 and I would like to read an outlook account (outlook.it).

Outlook SMTP is :

```
server: smtp-mail.outlook.com
port: 587 with TLS
```

and IMAP is :

```
server: imap-mail.outlook.com
port: 993 with SSL
```

Sending email is fine, but when I try to receive email with IMAP with method `receiveAndDelete` I get the following error:

```
jodd.mail.MailException: Message parsing failed; <--- javax.mail.MessageRemovedException
```

the email message is really deleted, but I dont want to get that exception.

How can i avoid this?

Comment: Hey, this should not be issue any more with 3.8 :) Does the answer helped ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug! Let me explain: Jodd copies data from received message to its own structure, however, this is done *after* the deletion flag is set. Therefore, mail library detects it is a deleted message and throws an exception.

Fixed [here](https://github.com/oblac/jodd/commit/c849ecada1a547a59c18849b62f79805967d833f), by parsing the message *before* setting the flags.

Workaround: don't use `receiveAndDelete` - instead receive and then delete later.